# iPhone Simulator screen is black when I have the app built and running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm 17 and quite new to all this however I've been learning for a while and have grasped the basics however I have encountered a problem of nothing being displayed when I build and run my app.

I am making a simple, "pong like game" that has a menu with four options, each a different "game" view, however I am just focusing on having the menu with one "game" view until I can figure out what is wrong beofre I add the other 3 views for the other 3 type of "game scene" (Tennis, Classic, ice rink, beach ball---using tennis atm). Here is the code for my AppDelegate.h file;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
ViewController *viewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Here is the AppDelegate.m file;

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

// Override point for customization after app launch
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}



@end
```

Next is the ViewContoller.h file;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIImageView *menuBG;

IBOutlet UIButton *playClassic;
IBOutlet UIButton *playTennis;
IBOutlet UIButton *playIceHockey;
IBOutlet UIButton *playBeachball;

IBOutlet UIImageView *court;
IBOutlet UIImageView *ball;
IBOutlet UIImageView *racquet_blue;
IBOutlet UIImageView *racquet_red;

IBOutlet UILabel *tapToBegin;


IBOutlet UILabel *player_score;
IBOutlet UILabel *computer_score;

CGPoint ballVelocity;

NSInteger gameState;
NSInteger previousState;

NSInteger player_score_value;
NSInteger computer_score_value;

IBOutlet UIButton *back;


}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *menuBG;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playClassic;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playTennis;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playIceHockey;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playBeachball;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *court;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *ball;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *racquet_red;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *racquet_blue;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel     *tapToBegin;


@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *player_score;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *computer_score;

@property(nonatomic) CGPoint ballVelocity;

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger gameState;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger previousState;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *back;

-(void)reset:(BOOL) newGame;


-(IBAction)playClassicButtonClicked;
-(IBAction)playTennisButtonClicked;
-(IBAction)playIceHockeyButtonClicked;
-(IBAction)playBeachballButtonClicked;
-(IBAction)BackButtonClicked;

@end
```

Here is the ViewContoller.m file;

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#define kGameStateRunning 1
#define kGameStatePaused  2
#define kStateMenu  1

#define kBallSpeedX 4
#define kBallSpeedY 6

#define kCompMoveSpeed 3
#define kScoreToWin 5

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize      ball,racquet_blue,racquet_red,player_score,computer_score,gameState,ballVelocity,tapToBegin,back,menuBG,playBeachball,playClassic,playIceHockey,playTennis,court,previousState;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if(gameState == kGameStatePaused) {
    tapToBegin.hidden = YES;
    gameState = kGameStateRunning;
} else if(gameState == kGameStateRunning) {
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
CGPoint xLocation = CGPointMake(location.x,racquet_blue.center.y);
racquet_blue.center = xLocation;
 }

-(void) gameLoop {
// Running
if(gameState == kGameStateRunning) {

    if (previousState != kGameStateRunning)
    {
        menuBG.hidden = 1;

        playClassic.hidden = 1;
        playTennis.hidden = 1;
        playIceHockey.hidden= 1;
        playBeachball.hidden = 1;

        ball.hidden = 0;
        court.hidden = 0;
        racquet_blue.hidden = 0;
        racquet_red.hidden = 0;
        player_score.hidden = 0;
        computer_score.hidden = 0;
        tapToBegin.hidden = 0;
        back.hidden = 0;

    }

    previousState = kGameStateRunning;
}
else if (gameState == kStateMenu)
{
    if(previousState != kStateMenu) {

        menuBG.hidden = 0;

        playClassic.hidden = 0;
        playTennis.hidden = 0;
        playIceHockey.hidden = 0;
        playBeachball.hidden = 0;

        ball.hidden = 1;
        court.hidden = 1;
        racquet_blue.hidden = 1;
        racquet_red.hidden = 1;
        player_score.hidden = 1;
        computer_score.hidden = 1;
        tapToBegin.hidden = 1;
        back.hidden = 1;
    }
    previousState = kStateMenu;


    }

    ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballVelocity.x , ball.center.y +    ballVelocity.y);

    if(ball.center.x > self.view.bounds.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
        ballVelocity.x = -ballVelocity.x;
    }

    if(ball.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height || ball.center.y < 0) {
        ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y;
    }

    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame,racquet_blue.frame)) {
        if(ball.center.y < racquet_blue.center.y) {
            ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y;
            NSLog(@"%f %f",ball.center,racquet_red.center);
        }
    }


    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame,racquet_red.frame)) {
        if(ball.center.y > racquet_red.center.y) {
            ballVelocity.y = -ballVelocity.y;
        }
    }


    // Begin Simple AI
    if(ball.center.y <= self.view.center.y) {
        if(ball.center.x < racquet_red.center.x) {
            CGPoint compLocation = CGPointMake(racquet_red.center.x - kCompMoveSpeed, racquet_red.center.y);
            racquet_red.center = compLocation;
        }


            if(ball.center.x > racquet_red.center.x) {
                CGPoint compLocation = CGPointMake(racquet_red.center.x + kCompMoveSpeed, racquet_red.center.y);
                racquet_red.center = compLocation;
            }
        }


    // Begin Scoring Game Logic
    if(ball.center.y <= 0) {
        player_score_value++;
        [self reset:(player_score_value >= kScoreToWin)];
    }


    if(ball.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height) {
        computer_score_value++;
        [self reset:(computer_score_value >= kScoreToWin)];
    }

    else {
    if(tapToBegin.hidden) {
        tapToBegin.hidden = NO;
    }
}
}

-(void)reset:(BOOL) newGame {
self.gameState = kGameStatePaused;
ball.center = self.view.center;
if(newGame) {
    if(computer_score_value > player_score_value) {
        tapToBegin.text = @"Computer Wins!";
    } else {
        tapToBegin.text = @"Player Wins!";
    }

    computer_score_value = 0;
    player_score_value = 0;
} else {
    tapToBegin.text = @"Tap To Begin";
}

player_score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",player_score_value];
computer_score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",computer_score_value];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
gameState = kStateMenu;
self.gameState = kGameStatePaused;
ballVelocity = CGPointMake(kBallSpeedX,kBallSpeedY);
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop)    userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}



-(IBAction)playClassicButtonClicked {
gameState = kGameStateRunning;
}

-(IBAction)playTennisButtonClicked {
gameState = kGameStateRunning;
}

-(IBAction)playIceHockeyButtonClicked {
gameState = kGameStateRunning;
}

-(IBAction)playBeachballButtonClicked {
gameState = kGameStateRunning;
}

- (IBAction)BackButtonClicked {
gameState = kStateMenu;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
// Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}




@end
```

I apologise for the amount of information, but I hope you will realise Im trying to make it as clear as possible to what I'm trying to show/achieve therefore making it easier for you to answer.

If you need any other information or spot any "Off topic mistakes" please feel free to tell me and I will be very thankful and post it up any missing info. I would incredibly appreciate any help, thanks Ryan :)

Comment: I also have everything up to daet software wise i.e. Xcode 4.5.2 and Im running MAC OS Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Answer (score 0):

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

instead of above

do this

```
window.rootViewController = viewController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the very quick reply! I tried replacing the info above but the screen is still black :/

Comment: reset your simulator and run it. let me know what you see

Comment: Still going to a black screen, although I have checked my connections in the .xib files could I have maybe made a mistake there ? Thanks :)

Comment: try setting the window backgrould color to red, and viewCotnroller.view background color to yellow. let me know which color you see

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController` and check if the control is coming to it...?

Comment: Ok, this is probably a stupid question but how will I know if control will be coming to it ?

Comment: you put a breakpoint at a particular line of code and run the app. When the control reaches that line, the app pauses and waits for manual interference of the developer. A quick video for basics of debugging : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKqDfYVSjg8

Comment: That video was great for explaining, however since my screen is black I can't interact etc with the app whatsoever to see if any thing is functioning.

Comment: Ryan, you are going wrong somewhere in the basic setup of your app delegate and its rootviewController. As @Tomasz mentioned, make sure the mainWindow or window is set as the main interface for your target. its quite possible that you are creating your own window, but an another window already exists, and that window is what is being displayed when you run the app.

Comment: It's all fixed now :) Thanks a lot for your help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why have you set the value of gameState twice ?

```
gameState = kStateMenu;
self.gameState = kGameStatePaused;
```

Clearly, when `gameLoop` is called, the value of gameState is `kGameStatePaused`.
And I dont see any functionality in `gameLoop` method for `kGameStatePaused`.

Maybe this could be the reason...

Comment: As I have explained I am pretty much a noob haha, so my fault. I deleted self.gameState = kGameStatePaused; and ran it again but the screen is still blank.

Comment: did you try putting breakpoints and debuging the code.? Things to check: 1. Is the `ViewController` really added as a subview to the window. (The color code technique mentioned by calvinBhai will help).
 2. Is the control going inside `gameLoop` method. If yes, is the required conditions being met as expected. Again add color codes within each condition inside `gameLoop` and check.

Comment: Also, why do you have `self.gameState = kGameStatePaused;` in `- (void)reset:(BOOL) newGame` ?? Maybe you can also set Repeat of NSTimer to NO just for testing..

Comment: Thanks. No I haven't tried that. Ive also did the color code thing to see if it's a subview and its still black unless Im missing something.

Comment: When the game is completed, i.e., player or computer scores 5 points everything will be reset accordingly with the game paused to prevent the ball from quickly dashing toward the player but instead giving them a chance to make sure they are ready if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose your window.xib as a Main Interface in Target's properties?

Comment: Hi, I put the main interface as MainWindow.xib which contains app delegate, view controller & window. SOMETHING APPEARS haha! However, I can't move my racket to play whereas the ball is automatically launched and the computer is continuously winning (keeps looping) I also cant go to menu and when the app starts it doesnt start in the menu but in the game.

Comment: This is, my friend, topic for the next question. It is good practice on Stackoverflow, not to change subject during discussion.
You got answer for this question, ask the next with new topic.